# Get Assembly From C# Project File

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a simple WinForm tool to assist with code generation, and I was wondering if it was possible to get the Assembly of one project into a different one that presides in a different solution.  I want the form to show all of the classes and then properties for each class, and the easiest/best way I can think of doing that is like:

```
private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
}
```

If the user selects a `.csproj` file, is it possible to get the Assembly?  Or is there a different way to get the classes/properties without recursively searching the project folder and parsing the files?

Comment: Would `nuget` do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csproj` file will contain the assembly name and the output directory.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>MyAppAssemblyNameOnly</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You'll have to add `.dll` suffix to it to get the actual file name.

The Output Path can be found in the different Configuration `<PropertyGroup>` nodes.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There's a couple of problems I can think of right off the bat.

- The DLL may not be built and so it won't exist.
- There are many different configurations with there being Debug and Release by default. You'll have to decide which one to look for.

For ease, you may just want to make the user feed you a DLL if the project is not part of the solution and you don't actually need anything else.

[You can also look into Roslyn and parse the files with Roslyn to get you all of the information you need too.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis)

Here's an example straight from their page. Seems super simple and straightforward. Kind of larger than I want, but don't want to just give a single link-only suggestion.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
                @"using System;
                using System.Collections;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;

                namespace HelloWorld
                {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                    }
                }
                }");

        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();

        var firstMember = root.Members[0];

        var helloWorldDeclaration = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)firstMember;

        var programDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)helloWorldDeclaration.Members[0];

        var mainDeclaration = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)programDeclaration.Members[0];

        var argsParameter = mainDeclaration.ParameterList.Parameters[0];

    }
}
```