# How to Regex match a pattern with parentheses in C#

Tags: c#, regex

**Background:** I'm doing some complicated code generation that requires me to extract the methods within a C# interface file. I cannot simply use reflection because this code will feed a T4 template which will not have the compiled code to reflect upon. Thus I am attempting parsing. I can easily make my own parser, but it would be nice if there was a regular expression solution.

**Question:** Is-there/What regex pattern would match the method declarations (including the return types and parameters) of the string below using C#'s Regular Expressions library?

```
    string testing = @"
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        public interface Service
        {
            int Test1(int a);

            int Test2(int a, int b);

            int Test3(
                int a,
                int b);

            int Test4(out int a);
        }
    }
    ";
```

The regex pattern I desire should make four matches:

1. "int Test1(int a);"
2. "int Test2(int a, int b);"
3. "int Test3( int a, int b);" [note: #3 would be multi-line]
4. "int Test4(out int a);"

**Solution Attempt:** Here is possibly the closest I have come to a regex solution thus far:

```
string WhiteSpacePattern = @"\s+";
string PossibleWhiteSpacePattern = @"\s*";
string CsharpWordPattern = @"[a-zA-Z_]+";
string ParenthesesPattern = @"[(][\s\S]*?[)]";

string DoubleCsharpWordPattern = CsharpWordPattern + WhiteSpacePattern + CsharpWordPattern;
string MethodDeclarationPattern =
    DoubleCsharpWordPattern +
    PossibleWhiteSpacePattern +
    ParenthesesPattern;
```

Pattern usage example:

```
MatchCollection tests = Regex.Matches(testing, MethodDeclarationPattern);
```

The individual patterns work perfectly (CsharpWordPattern, ParenthesesPattern, WhiteSpacePattern, and PossibleWhiteSpacePattern). However, when I put them altogether into a single pattern (MethodDeclarationPattern), the full pattern is failing.

**How does MethodDeclarationPattern or my usage example need to be altered so that it will start matching the method declarations in the interface code?**

Comment: You may be able to harness the power of Roslyn from the T4 to do the parsing for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935878/get-assembly-from-c-sharp-project-file/44936027#44936027

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match literal parens, escape them with backslashes:

```
string ParenthesesPattern = @"\([\s\S]*?\)";
```

That regex snippet matches a matched pair of parentheses, with optional whitespace between them. You're putting it at the end of your overall regex.

Your complete concatenated regex looks like this:

```
[a-zA-Z_]+\s+[a-zA-Z_]+\s*[(][\s\S]*?[)]
```

Identifier, space, identifier, open paren, space, close paren.

For that to match, the method declaration will have to look like this:

```
"int foo ()"
```

I believe you'll have better success with something like this:

```
string openParenPattern = @"\([\s\S]*?";
string closeParenPattern = @"[\s\S]*?\)";
```

What you really need, conceptually, is this (leaving out space -- no need to clutter it up with that):

1. identifier
2. identifier
3. open paren
4. ((ref|out)? identifier identifier comma)*
5. ((ref|out)? identifier identifier)?
6. close paren

You know all the syntax for that, I think. You'll have nested groups. Looking at it, I'm really starting to warm up to your idea of putting sub-regexes in string variables and then concatenating them.

The following code matches all four method declarations in your test string:

```
//  This has one bug: It matches "int foo(int a,)"
//  Somebody good with regexes could fix that. 
var methodPattern =
    //  return type
        identPattern + spacePattern
    //  method name
    + identPattern + spacePattern
    //  open paren
    + openParenPattern + spacePattern
    //  Zero or more parameters followed by commas
    + "(" + paramPattern + spacePattern + "," + spacePattern + ")*" + spacePattern
    //  Final (or only) parameter not followed by a comma
    + "(" + paramPattern + spacePattern + ")?" + spacePattern
    //  Close paren
    + closeParenPattern;
```

Comment: That's how you match a literal paren in .NET regular expressions. What your code does is match a *pair* of parens at the beginning, and another pair at the end. That doesn't appear to me to be what you need to match, and I think the fact that it *doesn't* match anything is a point in favor of my interpretation.

Comment: I like the literal version too. But either way the "ParenthesesPattern" is already working. The problem is when I form the final pattern "MethodDeclarationPattern" that the full pattern is failing. So something about merging the patterns together is causing a fail. It still fails even when I use the literal version.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I agree that your solution would work, but it seems more complicated than necessary. If I have to include some mild logic for multiple parameters and/or out parameters, then I would rather do the entire parsing myself and ignore Regex altogether. In the future I might need to include stuff like types with generic parameters, which would only make the regex that much more ridiculous. :D So I'm probably just going to parse it myself. Thanks :)

Comment: @ZacharyPatten Just added updated example code that finds all the method declarations. Not sure what's complicated about it though.

Comment: wow man! That worked perfectly. thanks! I'll try to review your example and figure out what I was doing wrong. I probably just have some false assumptions about how regex works.

Comment: @ZacharyPatten Awesome. See final update -- there were some redundant `\s`s